# How to modify a .exe.manifest dynamically?

Tags: c#, permissions, manifest, executable, system-administration

I have a manifest for an exe, which VS embedded into the exe. However I'm in a situation where I need to dynamically modify it. Is this possible?

Comment: and that situation is what exactly?

Comment: It certainly [seems possible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te.aspx).

Comment: I'm needing to make an application that may or may not require access permissions, under the circumstances.

Comment: If there *is* a way to handle it by setting system permissions you should really prefer that.

Comment: Changing an EXE file is not possible when the EXE was a loaded, Windows keeps a lock on the file.  Nor is it useful in the context of a manifest, Windows only reads it when the EXE starts.

Comment: It would be done just before the shutdown of the file, don't mind if I need to shut the process down and run a small command line exe after it.